# Merging two records with a common field and increment one field in MySQL & PHP

Tags: mysql, merge, increment, records

I have a table as follows. What I would like to avoid is having two product id's in the table. How can I merge the two common fields using a query and increment the quantity?

```
cartid |  prodid     | quanity |

   1   |  9226582    | 3       |

   2   |  9226582    | 5       | 

   3   |  7392588    | 1       |
```

The desired results is that the table should be altered as follows:

```
cartid |  prodid    | quanity |

   1   |  9226582   | 8       |

   3   | 7392588    | 1       |
```

I have searched for answers but all seem too complex. Is there a way to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the table in the database, you can do this:

```
create table newtable
   (`cartid` int, `prodid` int unique key, `quantity` int);

insert into newtable
   select * from yourtable order by cartid
   on duplicate key update quantity=newtable.quantity+values(quantity)

select * from newtable
```

Output:

```
cartid  prodid      quantity
1       9226582     8
3       7392588     1
```

If you're happy with the result you can then

```
drop table yourtable
alter table newtable rename to yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group by and min-

check this-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c4332/4

```
select min(cartid) cartid ,prodid,sum(quantity) quantity
from 
yourtable
group by prodid
order by cartid
```

create another table with same schema,
then

```
insert into newtable 
select min(cartid) cartid ,prodid,sum(quantity) quantity
    from 
    yourtable
    group by prodid
    order by cartid
```

Rename the newtable

Comment: thanx. i would want the table to actually be updated  in the database. How can i do this